# Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movie/1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: python, django, django-cors-headers

Every thing is normal but its not working, I have followed [https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/](https://stackoverflow.com),[https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers](https://stackoverflow.com) these documentation but its not working for me after that I have tried every possible solution available but its not working. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this why it is not working.
this is settings file of my project

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    "rest_framework",
    "cinemagic",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cinemagic_backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cinemagic_backend.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': "cinemagic",
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]
```

Comment: When DEBUG is True and ALLOWED_HOSTS is empty, the host is validated against ['.localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]'], try adding : ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']

Comment: No not working even I have tried with DEBUG=False but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what was the issue but my problem have resolved after changing the path.
earlier my path was this-

```
path("movie/<int:all>/", MovieView.as_view(), name="movie-view")
```

now i have changed the path to this-

```
path("movieview/<int:all>/", MovieView.as_view(), name="movie-view")
```

Comment: Changing the URL solved the issue? Hmm, sounds like caching to me. Try a hard refresh or clearing the cache in your browser if you want to keep the old URL.